# Skmaps visual advice images

Tags: ios, skmaps

I am using skobbler in my iOS application to integrate the navigation functionality. Whereas while navigating I see in the demo of the sdk that one gets visual advice images for turns and other information. I want all these possible visual images. I need to know from where are these picked and how are these created? I could not find anything in skobbler how tos about this. Please provide some additional information regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

After the route is calculated you can ask for all the advices. For each advice you will have a link to the corresponding visual image (with the `visualAdviceFile` property)

```
- (void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService didFinishRouteCalculationWithInfo:(SKRouteInformation*)routeInformation
{
    NSLog(@"Route is calculated.");
    NSArray* advices = [[SKRoutingService sharedInstance] routeAdviceListWithDistanceFormat:SKDistanceFormatMetric];
    for (SKRouteAdvice *advice in advices)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", advice.visualAdviceFile);
    }
}
```

From the documentation http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec15 and http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.3.0/Classes/SKRouteAdvice.html#//api/name/visualAdviceFile

Comment: How do you create these images. Actually I need to share these navigation advisory images via Bluetooth.Is there any full library of all the possible advisory images of skobbler I can have access to? Or I can find the way these are created.

Comment: The images are created via OpenGL on demand, based on the real road geometry (the angle between the roads in the image will match the angle between the real roads). So there isn't a collection of images that you could use but you'll have to get the list of images each time a route is created.